# Matching date range from to different data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe, date, if-statement, join

I am struggling days now to find a way to match two different tables (unbalanced in row number) in R with the matching range of dates.

The first data frame represents what someone has declared and the second data.frame represents what actually is.The problem is that an id say A might have kept for a week or more  a amount of product in kilos in his/her storage and then appear it one week after.

So i have two data frames with different rows. Both number for rows exceed 500.000.The first has 500.000 and the second 520.000.(so some NAs might occur but this doesn't matter).

I want to seach and match from these 2 different data frames:

1. the ids to are the same,
2. the product code and the man code to be the same, and
3. to check if  the date in the second data frame  is in the range of a month from the date in the first data frame (for example he/she declares a weight (100 kg) in 2020/1/1 and appears it in 2020/1/15 but the actual weight is 105).

and if all these conditions are true to sum the two weights (from the data frames 1 and 2)

The desired output must be a data frame with the matched id, range of date, the product , the man, the 2 columns weights and the last column to be  the values that will be the sum of the weights.

the example data frame are the two data frames in R  below :

```
id = rep("A",10)
date = seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), by = "day", length.out = 10)
product = c("E1","E1","E2","E3","E3","E4","E1","E1","E5","E5")
man = c("PS","PS","PS","DDR","DDR","FFR","PS","PS","BA","BA")
weight = c(1505,300,259,231,140,150,300,112,203,2200) 
data1 = data.frame(id,date,product,man,weight);data1


id2 = rep("A",10)
date2 = sample(seq(as.Date("2000/1/10"), by = "day", length.out = 10),10)
product2 = c("E3","E3","E1","E1","E1","E1","E5","E4","E5","E2")
man2 = c("DDR","DDR","PS","PS","PS","PS","BA","FFR","BA","PS")
weight2 = c(259,295,260,240,135,145,250,110,2000,210) 
data2 = data.frame(id2,date2,product2,man2,weight2);data2
```

How can I match them with the ginned date latency condition ?

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if it's what you want but it looks like a rolling join...

Using data.table and lubridate packages, one version could be:

(Here I show two examples one with 30 days forward and one with one month forward)

```
set.seed(0)

id = rep("A",10)
date = seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), by = "day", length.out = 10)
product = c("E1","E1","E2","E3","E3","E4","E1","E1","E5","E5")
man = c("PS","PS","PS","DDR","DDR","FFR","PS","PS","BA","BA")
weight = c(1505,300,259,231,140,150,300,112,203,2200) 
data1 = data.frame(id,date,product,man,weight);data1


id2 = rep("A",10)
date2 = sample(seq(as.Date("2000/1/10"), by = "day", length.out = 10),10)
product2 = c("E3","E3","E1","E1","E1","E1","E5","E4","E5","E2")
man2 = c("DDR","DDR","PS","PS","PS","PS","BA","FFR","BA","PS")
weight2 = c(259,295,260,240,135,145,250,110,2000,210) 
data2 = data.frame(id2,date2,product2,man2,weight2);data2

require(data.table)
require(lubridate)

setDT(data1)
setkey(data1)
setDT(data2)
setkey(data2)

data1[, weight_p50 := weight + 50]
data1[, weight_m50 := weight - 50]


data1[, date := as.Date(date)]
data2[, date2 := as.Date(date2)]
data1[, date_plus_one_month := as.Date(ymd(date %m+% months(1)))]
data1[, date_plus_30_days := as.Date(date + days(30))]

data2[, date2_ := date2]
data1[, date_ := date]

res <-
    data1[data2, list(id, product, man, date = date_, date2, weight, weight2, total_weight = weight + weight2),
          on = .(id = id2,
                 product = product2,
                 man = man2, 
                 date_plus_30_days >= date2, 
                 date <= date2_,
                 weight_p50 >= weight2,
                 weight_m50 <= weight2),
          allow.cartesian = TRUE, nomatch = 0
    ][][]
setkey(res, id, product, man, date, date2)
res <- unique(res, by = c("id", "product", "man"))
res[]
```

which gives:

```
   id product man       date      date2 weight weight2 total_weight
1:  A      E1  PS 2000-01-02 2000-01-16    300     260          560
2:  A      E2  PS 2000-01-03 2000-01-17    259     210          469
3:  A      E3 DDR 2000-01-04 2000-01-18    231     259          490
4:  A      E4 FFR 2000-01-06 2000-01-19    150     110          260
5:  A      E5  BA 2000-01-09 2000-01-12    203     250          453
```

EDIT: following OP comments, I added unicity on id x man x product such that it keeps only first dates satisfying the constraints.

Comment: it is very close to what I want but I don't want to search again and match other values.Like I want the unique() of your result

Comment: Basically to print only the first match. I.e the lines 1,9, 11 and so on.

Comment: I think with your example it is hard to understand for example in my code in data1 there are 4 dates (rows) for A/E1/PS with dates 2000-01-01/02/07/08 and 4 in data2 with dates 2000-01-10/11/14/16
Which rows should match and stay in the final result? do you want to keep only first dates in each dataframe? or aggregate in each data.frame ? (here I reported all matches (4x4=16 for A/E1/PS)
maybe dates should be unique in data1 for a combination of id x man x product ?

Comment: There must be kept the values of weight that are near the weight2 according to weight 1. I have implement your code in my real data set and work the same as your answer but I need only the near +-  50 weight2

Comment: That still is not clear. You said keep row 1 but weights are not different by less than 50? or you mean 50%?

Comment: NOT the first row.If you adjust your answer to keep the rows that the weight2 is +- 50 kg from weight 1.Please